# Column can not be null in ajax laravel update function

Tags: ajax, laravel

Hi guys i am sending my updated values from ajax to my update function.i am getting error as "Column cannot be null"

Here is my input which i am sending json data:

```
        <input type="text" id="jsonData" name="jsonData">
```

And here is my ajax form:

```
function saveEditQtypeFile(edit_qtype_id)
    {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

       chk_EnumValuesValidation = chkEnumValuesValidation(isSoltion, stepCount);
       if(!chk_EnumValuesValidation)
       {
           return false;
       }
        else
        {
            // Function to push "MainArray" in current Solution
            pushVarMainArrayInThisSolution(isSoltion, var_main_arr.var_arr_values);

            arr                = ar;
            var edit_qtype_id = $('#edit_qtype_id').val();
            var qtype_name = $('#qtype_name').val();
            var subject_list   = $('#qtype_subject_id').val();
            var ddl_topic_type = $('#qtype_topic_id').val();
            var qtype_option = $('#qtype_option').val();
            var jasondata = $('#jsonData').val();
            var sort_order = $('#sort_order').val();

            var sendInfo       = {
                'edit_qtype_id':edit_qtype_id,
                'arr':arr,
                'saveEditQtypeFile':1,
                'qtype_name':qtype_name,
                'qtype_subject_id':subject_list,
                'qtype_topic_id':ddl_topic_type,
                'qtype_option':qtype_option,
                'qtype_json':jasondata,
                'sort_order':sort_order
            };

            console.log('json',jasondata);
            //return false;

              //var loadQtypeInfo = JSON.stringify(sendInfo);
              $.ajax({
                url: "/eqtype-editor/update",
                type: "POST",
                data :sendInfo,
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",

                success: function(response)
                {
                    alert('Your file is updated!');
                    window.location.href ="/eqtype-editor";

                },
                error: function (request, status, error)
                {
                    alert('problem with updating record!!!');
                },
                complete: function()
                {}
            });
        }
    }
```

and here is my controller:

```
 public function update(Request $request, Qtype_editor $qtype_editor)
{

    $qtype_editor = Qtype_editor::findOrFail($request->edit_qtype_id);
    $qtype_editor->qtype_name = $request->input('qtype_name');
    $qtype_editor->qtype_subject_id = $request->input('qtype_subject_id');
    $qtype_editor->qtype_topic_id = $request->input('qtype_topic_id');
    $qtype_editor->qtype_option = $request->input('qtype_option');
    $qtype_editor->qtype_json = json_decode($request->input('jsonData'));
    $qtype_editor->sort_order = $request->input('sort_order');

    $qtype_editor->save();

    return redirect()->route('eqtype-editor.index');
}
```

From ajax when i console i am getting my json data..i am getting error as qtype_json cannot be null.

Can anyone help me where i am missing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check whether `qtype_json` included in your model's $fillable array

Comment: yes it was included  protected $casts = [
        'qtype_json' => 'array',
    ];

Comment: Do you have a $fillable or $guarded property on your model?

Comment: no i dont have it

Comment: Try defining `protected $guarded = []` on your model class

Comment: still getting same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a wrong key for your data.

Change the line in your controller:

```
$qtype_editor->qtype_json = json_decode($request->input('jsonData'));
```

to

```
$qtype_editor->qtype_json = json_decode($request->input('qtype_json'));
```

and it will work.